# Increment the 3rd octet in excel by value of 4

Tags: excel, networking, excel-formula, ip-address

I have a cell in excel with an ip address of 10.0.0.0 but I want to increment the third octet by 4. so the output of the next cell below will be 10.0.4.0

How can i make this happen without any complicated VB scripts if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula solution for Excel 2019 and up

Try to set up table as below

1] In **Octet** `D2`, enter position number of Octet by 1 to 4

2] In **Increment** `E2`, enter any value of Increment

Then,

3] In **Result** `B2`, enter array (CSE) formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",1,BITAND(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,".",REPT(" ",50)),{1;50;100;150},50))+IF(ROW(1:4)=D2,E2,0),{255;255;255;255}))
```

Or,

Using Filterxml function similar to mark fitzpatrick's formula.

In **Result** `B2`, enter array (CSE) formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",1,BITAND(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")+IF(ROW(1:4)=D2,E2,0),{255;255;255;255}))
```

[image]

Remark :

1] Try to change the Octet number by 1 to 4 and Increment value in testing of the result.

2] For Office 365 the formula will be normal entry

Comment: Hey Bosco - really nice work. The @ substitution is clever. The OP wants to Increment by 4 though. So, you need to pop out the third element, add E2 to it and then concatenate back in. Also, remember to BITAND when adding 4 because octets cannot be more than 255.

Comment: @mark fitzpatrick - post is edited, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me out. This saves me allot of time!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a formula that adds 4 to the third octet like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN( ".", 1,
           {0;0;4;0} +
           FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( A1, ".", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ) )
```

where A1 is where the target string "10.0.0.0" is held and the 4 is clearly in the third position.  You could also make this a generalized solution by putting in the offset that you want in the '{0;0;4;0}' array.

hmmmm - after further reflection, you need to ensure that the octets role over at 255.  Here is a safer version:

```
=TEXTJOIN( ".", 1,
           BITAND( {0;0;4;0} +
                     FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( A1, ".", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ),
                   {255;255;255;255} ) )
```